# ML.NET Model Builder with too many labels

Tags: ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I have a training set of 12k samples. Each sample is a result for my model.

For instance, i have 2 features and a label (f1 is a category and f2 a text):

```
F1,F2,LABEL
ALPHA, 114, ALPHA_114
ALPHA, 125, ALPHA_125
BETA, 213, BETA_213
```

I would match "ALPHA 113" in ALPHA_114 and not in BETA_213 (I would correct user's input).

I've trained 40 samples in about 40 seconds. After that, I wanted to train 120 samples but after 360 seconds no model were found.

How long do I need to train to learn from 12k samples?

I suppose the problem could be the too many labels that I have

**First solution** : I would split my training set in smaller sets that are more distant from each other, for example a set where `F1 like 'A*'`, `F1 like 'B*'` and so on.
Then, build a model for each set and merge theese models to create an unique big model.

Is this correct? Does there exist a way to merge different models? Is there a smarter way?

**Second solution** could be to create *n* ramdom sets (300 sets of 40 samples?), learn from single sets and merge the models. The questions are the same

Comment: Is all you want it to do is to concatenate the F1 and F2 columns? If so, you can just do a script for this.

Comment: No @Jon, I would build a model to evaluate new samples and get the correct prediction.